# -gt: unary operator expected message when running code

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

When running the following code:

```
DEAD_PROCESS_STATE=$(ps -o state | grep -i z | wc -l)

if [ ${DEAD_PROCESS_STATE} -gt 0 ]
then
     echo "..." 
else
     echo "..."
fi
```

I get the following message

```
line 12: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

Line 12 refers to the line

```
if [ ${DEAD_PROCESS_STATE} -gt 0 ]
```

I am not sure of what the issue could be, i have tried putting the zero inside single quotation marks but it still won't work. Can anyone see where the mistake could be? the code still runs and send out the correct email alerts i have set etc, I am just curious of what is causing this message to come up.

Comment: Could it by a typo? You read the result of your `ps` call into a variable `DEAD_PROCESS_STATE` but check on a (possibly uninitialized) variable `PROCESS_STATE`.

Comment: Ah yes i'm only realizing the typo now, how silly!

Comment: You may want to use `set -u` in your scripts. That would make the shell complain when you use uninitialised variables.

Comment: As an aside, you might be able to use `grep -c` in stead of `grep | wc -l`. Also, if you're using Bash as the tag shows, you could use `[[ .. ]]` instead of `[ .. ]`, it's smarter with quoting.

Comment: @May If the typo was the problem, you could delete the question. It gets only 'closed' otherwise, and will stay forever in our collection of Questions and answers, marked as unanswered, but somehow bad so that it can no longer be answered. (That's what normally happens, no problem with that.)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it." :)

Comment: I see, I got the message once myself, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 3):

You use the following command line:

```
if [ -gt 0 ]
```

since ${PROCESS_STATE} expands to nothing because it is an uninitialized variable.

For this reason, it is recommended to use something like:

```
if [ "${PROCESS_STATE}" -gt 0 ]
```

to make sure that you use the right number of arguments.

BTW: Check your text for typos and you will discover the reason, why `${PROCESS_STATE}`expands to nothing.

Comment: oops, sorry, I spoilered it in my "simultaneous" comment ..

Comment: See, once I do that I get the message line 12: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: Because the empty string is not an integer expression ,-) Did you correct the variable name yet?

Comment: haha what a silly mistake, thank you for pointing that out, it seems to be running fine now :)

Comment: Note that some `[` implementations like on some BSDs choke on blanks in operands to arithmetic operators like `-gt`, and some `wc` implementations do include blank in their output. Using `grep -ic z` instead of `grep -i z | wc -l` would make sure `$PROCESS_STATE` doesn't contain blanks.